# I have no access to container in my controller

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I am trying to access a service in a Symfony Controller

```
$session = $this->get('session');
```

But I get the next error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

I thought that Symfony2 had the controllers defined as services by default.

*Note: this question was originally asked by [Dbugger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392684/dbugger), but he removed it for no reason, while it was already answered.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Using the container in controllers

`get()` is only a shortcut function provided by the [Symfony base Controller class](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html) to access the container.

Your controller must extend this class to use this function:

```
namespace Acme\ExampleBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    // your actions
}
```

If you don't want to depend on this class (for some reasons) you can extend  [`ContainerAware`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.html) to get the container injected and use it like in the [`get()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L250) shortcut:

```
namespace Acme\ExampleBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class DefaultController extends ContainerAware
{
    public function exampleAction()
    {
        $myService = $this->container->get('my_service');

        // do something
    }
}
```

## Creating controllers on your own

Controllers are not defined as services per default, you can define them, but it's not needed to get the container. If a request is made, the routing framework determines the controller, which need to be called. Then the controller gets constructed and the container is injected via the [`setContainer()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.php#L37) method.

But if you construct the controller on your own (in a test or anywhere else), you have to inject the container on your own.

```
$controller = new DefaultController();
$controller->setContainer($container);
// $container comes trough DI or anything else.
```

Comment: deprecated since version 2.8, to be removed in 3.0. Use the ContainerAwareTrait instead.

Comment: @jan You can see how old the answer is? You can see this is a community wiki entry? Go and update edit that answer instead of mocking it's deprecated...