# Cannot access the saved ID of the associated entity directly without getting entire entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to understand why I cannot access the id field in my entity, when it is reference for an associated ID. I have read that this is the case, but I would like to know why given, the presence of an actual getter that should pull the data which IS in the database.

An in particular this is a problem, because I need to query my entity BASED on this id, e.g.

```
$article = $articleRepo->findOneByViewVersionId($view->getVersion()->getId());
```

I have an `Article` entity, that points to a `ViewVersion` entity with a uni-directional OneToOne association (because the viewVersion can point to a lot of different content types, I can't hard code this as bidirectional... I don't know how that's [another question I've posed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351457/how-to-create-dynamic-entity-association-with-doctrine2-in-symfony2)). This gets persisted to the database and a `viewVersionId` is set in the database (I see it there in that field). When I fetch the entity from the database, I can dump the entity and see ALL the fields, but the `viewVersionId` is reported as NULL, even though it has a value of 29 in the database!

```
class Article {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\View\ViewVersion")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="viewVersionId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $viewVersion;

    protected $viewVersionId;

    public function getViewVersion() {
        return $this->viewVersion;
    }

    public function getViewVersionId() {
        return $this->viewVersionId;
    }
}
```

If I fetch the entity and try to print out the viewVersionId directly, it's null:

```
// hard coded fetch for id 14 since $articleRepo->findOneByViewVersionId(29) doesn't work
$content = $articleRepo->find(14);
print('<h1>View version ID: '.$content->getViewVersionId().' (= NULL) </h1>');
print('<h1>View version ID: '.$content->getViewVersion()->getId().'(= 29) </h1>');

\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($content, 1); 
// this prints out all the fields but the viewVersionId is NULL
object(stdClass)#5095 (14) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=> string(38) "Gutensite\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article"
    ["content"]=> string(10) "Article 14"
    ["profileId"]=> NULL
    ["id"]=> int(14)
    ["lockVersion"]=> int(1)
    ["siteId"]=> NULL
    ["time"]=> int(1399935757)
    ["timeMod"]=> NULL
    ["timeDelete"]=> NULL
    ["flagDelete"]=> bool(false)
    ["userId"]=> NULL
    ["userIdMod"]=> NULL
    ["viewVersion"]=> string(43) "Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\View\ViewVersion"
    ["viewVersionId"]=> NULL
}
```

So why can't I access the viewVersionId value directly if the data is persisted to my database? I assume it's because of the OneToOne association, but in this case, the data is in my entity, and I have a getter, so why doesn't it work?

Comment: Can you try setting variables to `private` instead of `protected`? Also what is `$contentRepo` set to?

Comment: Changing the variable to private didn't make any difference ;( FYI, this is actually defined in a trait that the article entity calls with a `use` statement. But that shouldn't matter at all. I've set other variables in this trait, e.g. protected $foo = 1; and made getters for that, and they fetch just fine.

Comment: $contentRepo (or I've just updated it in my question to $articleRepo) is just the entityManager repository: `$articleRepo = $em->getRepository("GutensiteCmsBundle:Article");` And it works fine for doing a $articleRepo->find(14), but just can't do the ->findOneByViewVersionId(29).

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139970/getting-only-id-from-entity-relations-without-fetching-whole-object-in-doctrine

Comment: Yes I read that before posting my question. It is a similar problem, but he didn't directly define the field in the entity (or ORM), and he wasn't trying to do a findOneByFieldName(). It is interesting though, that theoretically getting the entity then the ID will not load the whole entity. Remy below hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$viewVersionId` in your entity is not visible to ORM at all. You need to add the correct annotation for it to be populated when Doctrine fetches the Entity from the database.

Try:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
pirvate $viewVersionId;
```

Comment: Genius! Of course I have to set the ORM metadata... I don't know how I dropped that off somewhere along the line of transitioning this to a trait and didn't notice. THAT solved the problem. So the getter didn't return the data, because it wasn't associated with the database as a column. Makes sense. I knew it *should* be accessible. Thank you. (bow)